# Tweaking my SQL Query to allow doc type in different Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please see below SQL Query, I'm looking to split the Document_Type column, when ever there is a comma.

```
 DECLARE @t TABLE(Company int,Date_Of_Birth DATETIME,Department VARCHAR(50)
,Document_Type VARCHAR(50), Name VARCHAR(50), Surname VARCHAR(50)
,ID_Number VARCHAR(50), Passport_No VARCHAR(50), Job_Title VARCHAR(50)
,Start_Date DATE,End_Date DATE, Type VARCHAR(50)
)
insert @t
SELECT 302,NULL,605,'New Employee Form','Richard', 'Watts',51086,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL union all
SELECT 302,NULL,605,'Personal Paticulars Form','Richard','Watts',51086,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL union all
SELECT 302,NULL,605,'Advance','Richard','Watts',51086,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL union all
SELECT 302,NULL,605,'Employment Agreement Signed','Richard','Watts',51086,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL union all
SELECT 302,NULL,605,'Inteview Record','Richard','Watts',51086,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL union all
SELECT 302,NULL,605,'leave Application','Richard','Watts',51086,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL union all
SELECT 302,NULL,605,'Doctor Certificate','Richard','Watts',51086,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL union all
SELECT 302,NULL,605,'Miscellaneous Documents','Richard','Watts',51086,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL

--Query ','+ ('')), 1,1,
SELECT DISTINCT ID_Number, Company, Date_Of_Birth,Department ,Name ,
Surname ,Passport_No, Job_Title,Start_Date,
End_Date ,Type, STUFF((SELECT ','+ Document_Type FROM @t WHERE ID_Number = Tmp.ID_Number FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,1,'')
FROM @t Tmp
```

THIS is the result.

7504145051086|302|NULL|605|Richard|Watts|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|New Employee Form,Personal Paticulars Form,Advance,Employment Agreement Signed,Inteview Record,leave Application,Doctor Certificate,Miscellaneous Documents

What I'm looking for is for it to run like this.
7504145051086|302|NULL|605|Richard|Watts|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|New Employee Form|Personal Paticulars Form|Advance|Employment Agreement Signed|Inteview Record|leave Application|Doctor Certificate|Miscellaneous Documents ....

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want the pipe ('|') char as separator for the string concatenation of you want every Job_Title in a different field? In the second case you need a dynamic `PIVOT`

Comment: My apologies, the pipe is represented by a new column, i don't want to add the pipe to the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the document type as fields instead of rows you need to use the `PIVOT`.
The main point here is that's there isn't a field to use to get the name of the pivoted field, so we have to create

```
With N AS ( 
  SELECT *
       , Pvt_Col = 'Document_Type_' 
       + CAST(Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Number 
                                 ORDER BY Document_Type) as VARCHAR) 
  FROM @t )
```

If the different values are known and few it's possible to fake it using `CASE`

```
With N AS ( 
  SELECT *
       , Pvt_Col = 'Document_Type_' 
       + CAST(Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Number 
                                 ORDER BY Document_Type) as VARCHAR) 
  FROM @t ) 
SELECT Company, Date_Of_Birth, Department, Document_Type, Name
     , Surname, ID_Number, Passport_No, Job_Title, Start_Date
     , End_Date, Type
     , Document_Type_1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Pvt_Col = 'Document_Type_1' 
                                  THEN Document_Type
                                  ELSE NULL
                             END)
     , Document_Type_2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Pvt_Col = 'Document_Type_2' 
                                  THEN Document_Type
                                  ELSE NULL
                             END)
...
FROM   N
GROUP BY Company, Date_Of_Birth, Department, Document_Type, Name
       , Surname, ID_Number, Passport_No, Job_Title, Start_Date
       , End_Date, Type
```

If the different values are more of unknown we have to use metascripting e.g. create a script to create the script to execute, this particular type of metascript is called dynamic pivot

```
Declare @q varchar(MAX)

With N AS (
  Select *
       , Pvt_Col = 'Document_Type_' 
       + Cast(Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Number ORDER BY Document_Type) as varchar)
  From   @t
), C (Cols) As (
  Select STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Pvt_Col) 
                FROM   N
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
              , 1, 1, '')
)
Select @q 
       = 'With N AS (
          SELECT *, Pvt_Col = ''Document_Type_'' 
               + Cast(Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Number ORDER BY Document_Type) as varchar)
          FROM   @t
        )           
        SELECT ID_Number, Company, Date_Of_Birth, Department, Name
             , Surname, Passport_No, Job_Title, Start_Date
             , End_Date, Type
             , ' + Cols + ' 
        FROM  (SELECT Company, Date_Of_Birth, Department, Document_Type, Name
                    , Surname, ID_Number, Passport_No, Job_Title, Start_Date
                    , End_Date, Type, Pvt_Col
               FROM N
           ) x
           PIVOT 
           (max(Document_Type) for Pvt_Col in (' + Cols + ')) pvt'
From C

execute(@q)
```

Comment: Hi Serpiton I have not worked with a syntax like this before, please will you explain to me how I should add this to my original script??

Comment: I have taken out my script, and replaced it with this one, this is the error? Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 't'.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, I think you almost got it, Im just doing not running this query correct, still getting the following error.Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Must declare the table variable "@t".

Comment: Oh ok I understand. to get the data from my first script I ran the below query `SELECT FD_0D39C6B0 AS Company, FD_DDD24E25 AS Date_Of_Birth , FD_74290EA9 AS Department,

 FD_2A7417DC AS Document_Type, FD_E3421C61 AS Name, FD_2B9CFA8C AS Surname,

 FD_96990BE2 AS ID_Number, FD_E6621D8A as Passport_No, 

 FD_3744C28A AS Job_Title, FD_903EBB60 as Start_Date,

 FD_9BBAD0CA AS End_Date, FD_AE108F93 as Type,
 CreatedOn AS DATE_SCANNED

FROM FD_Documents
 
where FD_96990BE2 = '51086'` so were the table is @q i need to but FD_Documents?

Comment: this is perfect, thank you so much, you have saved my bacon this day. i just ran this across the whole base and saw a funny.

Comment: if there is more than one entry, the column numbers get mixed up. like Document_Type_1,Document_Type_5,Document_Type_9,Document_Type_10,Document_Type_11, Document_Type_12

Comment: Can we have this Document number running from 1 to however many?

Comment: you have replicated the issue I have, in the link you sent, if you look at the document type columns, you will see Document_Type_1, then Document_Type_10, it should show then Document_Type_2 then 3 and 4 and 5.

Comment: i owe you a case of beer... :-)

Comment: @serpition, the tweak you made is working great, just a small change an cannot seem to get it to work. I'm trying to get all the document types to be in the same column, like All Inteview Record in a column for different ID numbers all Advance in the same column for different ID. I'm not sure this can be done, because there is no set list for Document type? What is your thoughts on this?

Comment: sorry miss spelt your user

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_Number, 
Company, 
Date_Of_Birth,
Department ,
Name ,
Surname ,
Passport_No, 
Job_Title,
Start_Date,
End_Date ,
Type, 
STUFF((SELECT '|'+ Document_Type 
       FROM @t 
       WHERE ID_Number = Tmp.ID_Number 
       FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,1,'')
FROM @t Tmp
```